# Spelling checker always does grammar check as well

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

In my Office 365 version of Word the user interface for the spell checker recently changed. It now looks like this...

[image: Spell check UI]

It is slow to load and I cannot turn off the grammar checking.

When I go to the Proofing Settings, I see this ...

[image]

Notice that **Mark grammar errors as you type** is unticked, and there is no **Check grammar with spelling** tickbox.

How do I turn off grammar checking?

This "Editor" pane, which always shows Spelling and Grammar -- is there  way to turn it off and revert to the old-style spell-check pane?

Comment: What is the format of your document? .doc or .docx?

Comment: It is a `.docx` file

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the Options > Proofing dialog there is an **"Exceptions for:"** pull-down menu. You can change its value to **All New Documents** and then mark the check box to **"Hide grammar errors ..."**

Comment: Sorry to say, but that does not work. When I turn that option off, then create a new document, type a few words and then press F7 for the spelling checker, I get the error message "To check this document the following exceptions in Proofing Options must be turned off: Hide spelling errors in this document only; Hide grammar errors in this document only". I have tried every combination of those two tick boxes in the Proofing options for "this document" and "all documents" and I always get one of two behaviours -- either the error message I mentioned here, or the behaviour I described in the OP.